# How do I get roblox on Raspberry PI 4 - OS: Raspbian. (NOOBS)

Tags: pi-4

Someone help. I have looked everywhere to find an answer. Please tell me how.

Comment: You can install windows 10 on your Pi

Answer (score 2):

Roblox is not supported on the Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome,

Going by [this link](https://corp.roblox.com/technology/) the clients are only available for

> iOS and Android, to Mac, PC, Xbox One, Oculus Rift, and HTC Vive.

Even the Pi 4 does not have the power to emulate a PC or Android phone so I am afraid you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't personally tried this, but you may be able to install Android and play the Android version on the Pi. However it probably won't run very well because the Pi is not that fast. There's also a chance it won't run at all because as I said I haven't tried it yet.

If you want to try it, I'd recommend this article from PiMyLifeUp: https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-android/

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to run it on a regular os.
this guy got it working on a version of android tv
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t_SxaZDGdKA&ab_channel=leepspvideo

Comment: It's better to give an answer rather than just a link as Stack Exchange has no control over other sites so if the video is taken down the knowledge is lost.  The other advantage is as operating systems change, new answers can be added or the original updated where the external site remains as is.